# Assignment operator on vectors with different const correctness

Tags: c++, stl

I have a really simple method:

```
void SomeClass::GetListStuff(std::vector<Stuff const *> &listStuff) const
{   listStuff = m_listStuff;   }
```

Where m_listStuff is a member of SomeClass and is of type

```
std::vector<Stuff *>
```

This code gives me an error saying

```
there's no match for 'operator='
in 'listStuff = ((const SomeClass*)this)->SomeClass::m_listStuff
```

It works fine if I take the const away from the ListStuff pointer. I can also call insert() on listStuff (without changing the const correctness) and it works. Could anyone explain why?

Comment: Is there some particular reason you're not just *returning* the list object by const reference? `const std::vector<Stuff const *>& SomeClass::GetListStuff() const { return m_listStuff;};` and assigning back in the caller? If neither that, nor your code works then perhaps you should investigate the *types* of both to ensure they're identical?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should do this:

```
void SomeClass::GetListStuff(std::vector<Stuff*> &listStuff) const
{   
       listStuff = m_listStuff;   
}
```

That is, use `std::vector<Stuff*>` instead of `std::vector<Stuff const*>` because I suspect that `m_listStuff` is declared to be `std::vector<Stuff*>`. So the argument type should match that.

I think a better approach would be this:

```
std::vector<Stuff*> SomeClass::GetListStuff() const
{   
       return m_listStuff; //return a copy!
}
```

Or even better is to expose iterators:

```
std::vector<Stuff*>::const_iterator cbegin() const
{   
       return m_listStuff.cbegin(); //return const_iterator (C++11 only)
                                    //in C++03, you can use begin()
                                    //it will work same as cbegin()
}
std::vector<Stuff*>::const_iterator cend() const
{   
       return m_listStuff.cend(); //return const_iterator (C++11 only)       
                                  //in C++03, you can use end()
                                    //it will work same as cend()
}
```

Write the non-const version yourself.

Comment: the types *are* different... but won't c++ take care of const conversion implicitly? I can manually assign the pointers directly [using push_back or insert on the vector even though they're different types] but directly assigning them doesn't work.

Comment: @Pris: That is not going to work here. `std::vector<T> &` can convert  to `std::vector<T> const &`, but `std::vector<T> &` cannot convert  to `std::vector<T const>&`. See the difference.